# DOS Batch File Command does not execute

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

The following command line executes properly:

```
 MagBoltz32 < input.txt > out.txt
```

The executable requires the input in brackets as above and outputs the text file.  The following "batch.BAT" file (now including the escape characters) does NOT execute but simply hangs as if expecting more input.

```
 MagBoltz32 ^< input.txt ^> out.txt
```

Executing batch.BAT simply results in a blinking cursor.  Ultimately this command line will go into FOR loop which loops over several input/output files.  I do have access to the source code.

Comment: Second command does not look like valid syntax at all. Not surprised that it doesn't work. No need to escape that.

Comment: `MagBoltz32` seems to expect data at _STDIN_ (console input); `<` constitutes a redirection operator telling that the content of `input.txt` is redirected to _STDIN_; if you escape redirection like `^>`, the executable awaits console input (type something in and when finished type `Ctrl+Z` (end-of-file code) and _enter_), then you will receive output data; `>` redirects console output a file `out.txt`, so if you escape that like `^>`, I assume you will get the output in the console window...

Comment: There is only one command (executable) requiring two inputs.  The first input looks for a text file and requiring that file to be in brackets.  The second input is the output file.

Comment: In short: `MagBoltz32 < input.txt > out.txt` means execute `MagBoltz32` and redirect both input and output; this works in the command line or in a Batch file. `MagBoltz32 ^< input.txt ^> out.txt` is an entirely different thing where no input and output are redirected.

Comment: ... unless the command is placed in a `for /F` command enclosed in apostrophes: `for /F %%a in ('MagBoltz32 ^< input.txt ^> out.txt') do ...` This is the only case when this command must be written this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not "input in brackets". The programm doesn't use any parameters (at least not in the shown syntax). It gets it's input from STDIN and writes to STDOUT.

`<input.txt` redirects the content of `input.txt` to STDIN, so the program is able to use it, like it were entered per keyboard.
`>output.txt` redirects STDOUT to the file `output.txt` instead of writing it to the screen.

Escaping characters is only needed, if you want the special char to be shown on the screen instead of "executing" it (simply spoken), so in your case, escaping the redirection characters makes no sense, but disables the redirection.

Comment: The output to the command line for a batch file with the line "MagBoltz32 < input.txt > out.txt" is  "MagBoltz32 0<input.txt 1>out.txt" however the out.txt is correct and was successfully executed.  THANKS

Comment: That's ok. `<` is just an short form for `0<` ("0"=STDIN), `>` for `1>` ("1"=STDOUT). If no number is given, the parser inserts the default value.

Answer (score 0):

In some OS's you need to escape the pipes <, > and | so the syntax could be completely valid. This is particularly true for batch files (http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php) ... Have you checked to make sure all the files are in the same path that is executing the batch file? If you run the batch from C:\foo even though bath.BAT is in c:\bar, the input.txt will be expected to be in C:\foo.

Comment: I did check.  I incorrectly escaped the redirect operators